# How to take two different Firebase account users to different activities?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm creating an android application, my app contains two types of user accounts linked with firebase, when the users log in to their accounts, the first user(teacher) should be carried to a different activity than the second (student) user.

I tried the if statements but I don't know how to distinguish between the teacher and student account.

Comment: are you able to distinguish at the point of registration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the type of user when creating the account. Try to store that data in Firestore or Realtime Database.

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:{
date:"2019-07-16",
id:"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
name:"Teacher1",
type: "teacher"
}
```

Fetch and identify the type of user at the time of login. Then you can navigate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a userType value in the database. Then you check this value at the input and direct it accordingly.

For example if the logged-in user is admin, I wrote a code so that the button appears:

```
 if (user.getAdmin().trim().equals("true")) {
            cardDesingHolder.isThatAdmin.setText("Admin");
            cardDesingHolder.Admin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cardDesingHolder.Admin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, AdminPanel.class));
                }
            });
        } else {
            cardDesingHolder.isThatAdmin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            cardDesingHolder.Admin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

There is a part called admin in my database. If this value is true, the button appears, otherwise it does not. You can do something like that.

My Database Example : http://prntscr.com/opxm9e